# How can I list content of installed gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Some gems ("sup" for example) install files not only in `gem environment gemdir`, but also in other places - like /usr/local/bin.

How can I list all files that belong to given gem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
gem contents gem_name_here
```

Comment: It is pretty cool, but it lists only what's installed in "gemdir". And doesn't list files in other locations (like in /usr/local/bin in case of `sup`)

Comment: @chu4Meek4e: the stuff in `/usr/local/bin` are normally links to stuff in `/path/to/gem/bin`

Comment: Yup, if it's under the gem bin directory, it will be copied somewhere in your pathm (or included in your path, if you're using RVM).

Comment: Executable files are copied by `gem` inside the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` shown by the command `gem env`.

Comment: This is not true. Files in /usr/local/bin are not links. @toro2k The files in /usr/local/bin/* are not the same as in gemdir/bin/*.

Comment: then you have a completely different machine than everyone else or you are using a Ruby manager like RVM. Call  `gem env` and look for `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`, your gem executables should be installed there. If they aren't you have a broken Ruby install.

Comment: I have normal (?) debian. No rvm. Did you try installing "sup"? Here you have all the information from my machine, that I assumed to be related: http://pastebin.com/PTMrnHnE

Comment: One more bit of information - gem apparently "knows" about these binaries in /usr/local/bin - as it asks specifically about removing them when doing "gem uninstall sup"

Comment: And what are you looking for here? All binaries are copied at `/usr/local/bin/`. What is missing here? They were copied at the time the gem was installed in your system. I don't understand what you're asking here anymore.

Comment: They are **not** copied. The files are different!

Answer (score 2):

To view the content:

`bundle open gemname`

Comment: `bundle open sup` returns "Could not locate Gemfile", despite the fact that I have the sup gem installed: http://depesz.privatepaste.com/f421213337

Comment: That only works if you're using bundler to manage your dependencies... which is a good idea, OP!!!

Comment: "manage my dependencies"? I just installed gem from internet. How is it related to my dependencies?